# Best practice pass the simple variable value to another scope in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to access the variable from outside present scope. I want use best practice for accessing the variable from outside.

**My Requirement:** let me tell the situation I had generated url in one scope from collecting data from select option  in this success scope and in next success I will fetch the json data using this url, How I will do

**DEMO :** http://plnkr.co/edit/wIk0dwiDwgWlOLrAvjX5?p=preview

```
 $http.get("data.json")  // this will give some data from which i will made select options
.success(function(response) {  
      // generate dynamic url        
      var dyanamic_url="http://192.168.206.133:8080/admin/metering/<select_options>;
      //alert(url);
    });
  //I wanted to use this dyanamic_url outside scope.
 //Outside the scope of success.
 $http.get(dyanamic_url)
.success(function(response) {
      // Fetch JOSN DATA
})
```

**Will following work?**

```
.success(function (response) { 
       var url = response.someproperty; 
       http$.get(url).success(function(respone ))  
 });
```

Comment: you can't, that scope will be long done executing by then.

Comment: @KevinB  I want to access the url from outside, how I will do Please help me on this..

Comment: you won't do that. it isn't possible. It will still be undefined when you try.

Comment: One way is to use the actual $scope object. Perhaps initiate it at the beginning of your controller as `$scope.url = "";` Then you can access it both inside and outside of a success function.

Comment: Or you have to store this data in a service. And the inject this service

Comment: Or make `url` a global variable (although not recommended)

Comment: @KevinB let me tell the situation I had generated url in one scope from collecting data from select option this is in success scope and in next success I will fetch the json data using this url, How I will do

Comment: Perform the second http request inside the success of the previous.

Comment: @DougEFresh no need to pollute scope with variables that aren't related to view and are only used within internals of controller

Comment: There was less code in initial post, for all I knew he wanted to put it on the view. "outside of scope" is a pretty general term.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to get access to `url` in that scope. Instead, simply send the second request inside of the success callback.

```
.success(function (response) {
    var url = response.someproperty;
    sendAnotherRequest(url);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, How to declare  function sendAnotherRequest in angularjs

Comment: Replace it with $http or whatever you're using to send the request.

Comment: .success(function (response) {
    var url = response.someproperty;
       http$.get(url) .success(function(respone  )) This will work..
});